# Touching water after daily puja - sãdhanã bad?

Tags: belief, puja, sadhana, upasana

I have heard

> that one **must not** touch water after having finished their daily
> *pújã/upãsanã - पूजा/उपासना*. This is because, that due to *mantra-uccharaña - मंत्रोच्चारण* while doing *sãdhanã - साधना*, a great amount of sound vibrational energy due to the *mantra* is
> generated and thus, subsequently, the spiritual power of the person is
> increased. 
> However, immediately touching the water after one's *sãdhanã* is finished, results in the
> transfer of the spiritual energy ( that's generated in the body) directly to
> the water and the *sãdhaka - साधक*,  looses all the spiritual merits
> done for that particular *sãdhanã*. Thus, one **must refrain** from,
> immediately touching any water after finishing their *pújã-sãdhanã* and
> wait for sometime on *pújã-ãsana* only, for the generated energy to be
> well absorbed within the body.

So, what might be the scriptural references for these beliefs, if any?

Comment: Touching water Or Upa Sparsha (like Achamana) is a purificatory process. And Achaman is recommended to be performed both at the start as well as at the conclusion of the ritual. So I would be surprised if Upasparsha is prohibited after the conclusion of the Puja.